# How to analyze jstatd issue where Java processes are not listed?

Tags: java, profiling, jstatd

Up until recently I was able to successfully run jstatd (`jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=c:\path\to\jstatd.policy`) and visualvm (1.3.5) on a Windows 2008 server box. All the running Java (1.6.0_31) processes were listed properly. For some reason I cannot view some of the running processes anymore and they are indeed running. What can I do to properly analyze this?

My policy file looks like the default example from the jstatd site:

```
grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I am unsure how to further investigate this. I have exactly the same set up under Linux and it works fine.

Comment: Not sure what your problem exactly is, but `jps` enlists all running java processes on local machine

Comment: I'm afraid `jps` is not listing the application which is indeed running.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287926/jps-not-showing-tomcat-process

Comment: It appears the Java application is actually wrapped as an `.exe`. Any suggestions how to run profiling on that?